# Flink: DataSource's outputs caused an error: Could not read the user code wrapper

Tags: apache-flink

I Am just starting flink. I wrote following code and got 
"**DataSource's outputs caused an error: Could not read the user code wrapper**" error

Is there any thing I am doing wrong?

version : Flink v 0.9.1 (hadoop 1) not using hadoop: Local execution
shell: scala shell

**Code:**

```
val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val text = env.readTextFile("/home/ashish/Downloads/spark/synop.201501.csv"
val data_split = text.flatMap{_.split(';')}
data_split.first(3).print()
```

Note: The input file uses ';' as deliminator

Error:

```
    Scala-Flink> val data_split = text.flatMap{_.split(';')}
data_split: org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet[String] = org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet@60f70249
Scala-Flink> data_split.first(3).print()
09/24/2015 09:20:14 Job execution switched to status RUNNING.
09/24/2015 09:20:14 CHAIN DataSource (at $line26.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.<init>(<console>:14) (org.apache.flink.api.java.io.TextInputFormat)) -> FlatMap (FlatMap at $line27.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.<init>(<console>:15))(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED 
09/24/2015 09:20:14 CHAIN DataSource (at $line26.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.<init>(<console>:14) (org.apache.flink.api.java.io.TextInputFormat)) -> FlatMap (FlatMap at $line27.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.<init>(<console>:15))(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING 
09/24/2015 09:20:14 CHAIN DataSource (at $line26.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.<init>(<console>:14) (org.apache.flink.api.java.io.TextInputFormat)) -> FlatMap (FlatMap at $line27.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.<init>(<console>:15))(1/1) switched to FAILED 
java.lang.Exception: Call to registerInputOutput() of invokable failed
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:504)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The initialization of the DataSource's outputs caused an error: Could not read the user code wrapper: $line27.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.registerInputOutput(DataSourceTask.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:501)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.CorruptConfigurationException: Could not read the user code wrapper: $line27.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.TaskConfig.getStubWrapper(TaskConfig.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.RegularPactTask.instantiateUserCode(RegularPactTask.java:1507)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.ChainedFlatMapDriver.setup(ChainedFlatMapDriver.java:39)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.ChainedDriver.setup(ChainedDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.RegularPactTask.initOutputs(RegularPactTask.java:1378)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.initOutputs(DataSourceTask.java:290)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.registerInputOutput(DataSourceTask.java:86)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $line27.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil$ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InstantiationUtil.java:71)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:302)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.readObjectFromConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:264)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.TaskConfig.getStubWrapper(TaskConfig.java:282)
    ... 8 more

09/24/2015 09:20:14 Job execution switched to status FAILING.
09/24/2015 09:20:14 CHAIN GroupReduce (GroupReduce at org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet.first(DataSet.scala:707)) -> FlatMap (collect())(1/1) switched to CANCELED 
09/24/2015 09:20:14 DataSink (collect() sink)(1/1) switched to CANCELED 
org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$receiveWithLogMessages$1.applyOrElse(JobManager.scala:314)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.ActorLogMessages$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogMessages.scala:43)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.ActorLogMessages$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogMessages.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:118)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.ActorLogMessages$$anon$1.applyOrElse(ActorLogMessages.scala:29)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.aroundReceive(JobManager.scala:92)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:254)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:221)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Call to registerInputOutput() of invokable failed
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:504)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The initialization of the DataSource's outputs caused an error: Could not read the user code wrapper: $anonfun$1
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.registerInputOutput(DataSourceTask.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:501)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.CorruptConfigurationException: Could not read the user code wrapper: $anonfun$1
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.TaskConfig.getStubWrapper(TaskConfig.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.RegularPactTask.instantiateUserCode(RegularPactTask.java:1507)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.ChainedFlatMapDriver.setup(ChainedFlatMapDriver.java:39)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.ChainedDriver.setup(ChainedDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.RegularPactTask.initOutputs(RegularPactTask.java:1378)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.initOutputs(DataSourceTask.java:290)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.registerInputOutput(DataSourceTask.java:86)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $anonfun$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil$ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InstantiationUtil.java:71)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:302)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.readObjectFromConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:264)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.TaskConfig.getStubWrapper(TaskConfig.java:282)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Few things to help answering this: (1) The third line (getting the new execution environment) should not be removed. Mixing different environments will probably cause issues (and may be the reason for your problem here, in fact). (2) Can you post the full exception stack trace. The root cause is missing, it should be under "caused by" further down in the stack trace. (3) Your code example seems to have truncated lines, can you post the full lines?

Comment: the val env should have been the first line... I am sorry about that .val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironmentval text = env.readTextFile("/home/ashish/Downloads/spark/synop.201501.csv"
val data_split = text.flatMap{_.split(';')}
data_split.first(3).print()

Comment: I have updated the full error log

Comment: Okay, thanks. Can you try it completely without "val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment"? IIRC, there should already be a pre-defined "env" variable.

Comment: Thank you it worked.... adding the env was the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the statement "val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment" in the first line.

The Scala Shell already has an ExecutionEnvironment, bound to the variable "env", which is configured for proper loading of the classes generated by the Shell.

By creating a new ExecutionEnvironment, you override that pre-configured environment with one that is not properly set up.

Comment: Stephan, could you specify a link on how should be flink program locally tested in repl? I have the same problem with flink 1.2 project that is developing in emacs-ensime environment. `env.readTextFile("file:/d:/data/test.csv").first(5).print()` works fine, however  `env.readTextFile("file:/d:/data/test.csv").map(_.split(' ')).first(5).print()` - not.

Comment: And it works properly in windows cmd in sbt console. In ensime-inferior-scala `org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.CorruptConfigurationException: Could not read the user code wrapper: $anonfun$1`.